# how to navigate from UIWebview to my application view

Tags: objective-c, ios4, iphone

i am having problem in navigating from UIWebview to back on my application screen in iphone,
as the my iphone is not having multitasking functionality.
for eg:- my application has web based registration process. when the application is download then the user has signup button on which i have given link to website then after registering it user has to come back to application window

thanks in advance

Comment: Would you post your code that makes the UIWebView to come back to app screen?

Comment: Are you using a UIWebView or are you launching mobile safari to do the login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has this application already been approved by Apple?

If not then you may want to rethink your design before you spend too much time trying to solve this problem.  Put simply, if you require users to register on an external site in order to use your app, it is very unlikely to get approved for the app store.  The official guideline is:

> Apps cannot require user registration prior to allowing access to app
>   features and content that are not associated specifically to the user.
>   User registration that requires the sharing of personal information
>   must be optional or tied to account-specific functionality.
>   Additionally, the requested information must be relevant to the
>   features.

I'm not saying I endorse this requirement, but you should be aware of it so that you don't waste your time solving this problem only to find that Apple won't accept your app.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass some parameters to your registration form when press button in your app, so your site may know what it can redirect to specific scheme url, which will be handled by your application.

Add this entree into Info.plist

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>myAppScheme</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

And now you can redirect user after registration to URL **myAppScheme**://maybeSomeTokenHere and your application will be launched and pass this parameter to it.